# Countif dynamic criteria range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have spreadsheet which contains values like
csrini/Zircon Free csrini PAC PAC PAC PAC PAC PAC PAC PILLAR PILLAR

I want to exclude the certain text such as (PAC PDU and Pillar ). 
I want to use a dynamic `COUNTIF` formula so that when I want to add to the exclusions I can do it without much work.

Is it possible to add a range in the criteria?  Currently I am using the formula below.

```
 =COUNTIFS(B6:M6,"<>*PAC*",B6:M6,"<>*PDU*",B6:M6,"<>*PILLAR*",B6:M6,"<>*Free*")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To make this work dynamically, you need to use an array formula.

First define your words to exclude a column somewhere.  I will use `A:A` in this example.  I will also use `B:B` as the range to search.

The formula for a non-case sensitive search is:

```
=COUNTA($B:$B)-SUMPRODUCT((IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA($A:$A))),$B:$B)),0,1)))
```

For a case sensitive search change `SEARCH` to `FIND`

```
=COUNTA($B:$B)-SUMPRODUCT((IF(ISERROR(FIND(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA($A:$A))),$B:$B)),0,1)))
```

Array formulas are entered using `crtl` + `shift` + `enter`

This formula first gets the entire count of column B that is not empty using `COUNTA` then subtracts from that, the count of the criteria from `A:A` found within `B:B`.  It checks using `SEARCH` or `FIND` for each criteria value in column `B:B` which then `SUMPRODUCT` sums all the matches up.

An important part to note is the `TRANSPOSE`, this is only needed because I kept my criteria in a column list.  If you keep your criteria in a row instead of a column then remove the transpose, the `FIND` function just needs it to be a horizontal array.

Whenever you add a data row in column A the `INDIRECT` formula updates the range so you do not have to update it manually.